# Java: Pattern for updating all equal objects (in the same context) that don't share the same reference

Tags: java, jpa, equals, cdi, session-scope

In my java application I am using equal objects multiple times at different places. That means the equals method returns true, when comparing theses objects. Now I want to update one object and make the changes to all objects that are equal. Do you know if there is a pattern for that?

My concrete use case is:
I am using JSF, JPA and CDI. A user is on web page that allows him to edit the detached entity EntityA. The page is sessionscoped. EntityA has two references to an EntityB (also detached). These objects can be same. Not the same reference, but they may be equal.

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
   @OneToOne()
   private EntityB entity1;
   @OneToOne();
   private EntityB entity2;
}
```

The JSF view lets the uses select entity1 and entity2 from a selection list. It also shows some details of theses EntityBs and the user is allowed to edit entity1 and entity2 seperately. Everything works fine, except the user has choses the same (equal) EntityB for entity1 and entity2. Then, only the references to these objects are updated. Of course entity1 and entity2 are two different JPA entites, and are not the same reference. But I want to distribute the changes to all detached instances of EntityB. I have this situation hundreds of times in my application, so I dont want to take care about, which objects have to be updated in which situations. I need some solutation the does it for me automatically. One Idea was to keep all objects I use in this session in special list and every time a request was submitted and processed iterate over this map and change alle equal objects. But his sounds very dirty. Maybe there is a build in JPA function to make all equal objects the same reference. I dont know if this is possible. Do you have a solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to abstract your problem out a bit here: if a change to one object requires changing a number of other objects, consider putting the field that you're changing in a separate object, and have all those objects reference it.

For example, if you have:

```
class MyClass {
  String info;
  int id;
}
```

and two instances of MyClass with the same 'id' should both be updated when the 'info' field changes then use this:

```
class myClass {
  myInfoClass info;
  int id
}

class myInfoClass {
  String value;
}
```

and give all instances of `myClass` that are equal the same instances of `myInfoClass`. Changing `myClass.info.value` will effectively change all instances of `myClass`, because they all hold the same instance of `myInfoClass`.

Sorry if I've got the syntax slightly wrong, I jump between languages a lot.

I use this technique in a game I wrote recently where a switch activates a door- both the switch and door have a `Circuit` object that holds a boolean `powered` field. The doors 'isOpen()' method simply returned `circuit.powered`, and when the switch is activated I just call `switch.circuit.powered = true`, and the door is automatically considered 'open'. Previously, I had it searching the game's map for all doors with the same circuit id, and changing the `powered` field on each.

Comment: Ok. I know what you mean. But I cannot use it, because I have huge domain model that is managed by JPA (hibernate). Even if I used the myInfo-Subclass it would be managed by hibernate. So I had a new instance of the same object.

Comment: Ah, fair enough- I'm not that familiar with JPA, but it sounded very similar to a pattern I've seen a few times.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed description. I am sure it worked, if there wasn't this JPA mapping tool that has control over all my object instances.

Answer (score 0):

this is classic form handling logic

- if the user clicks the save button manipulate the data in the database
- reload the data every time you create the web page
- you should not cache the data in the web session
- if you need caching, activate it in the persistence layer (ex. hibernate cache)

Comment: I need to cache the data in the session anyway. Because the JSF view uses ajax requests to let the user edit a huge object tree over hundrets of requests. nothing is saved until the user clicks the save button.

Comment: the problem is, I cannot be sure, that equal objects are the same reference. If there was a pattern or I hibernate setting that could assure that, it would be really great.

Comment: seems like you need to find a way to keep the persistence session alive across the ajax requests. otherwise you would just replicate what hibernate does under the hood. in the same persistence session hibernate will return the same object for the same id.

Comment: do you know how to do this using ejb? i am using the @EJB annotation in my controllers to access the data services. even when i set the session bean to \@stateful and \@persistencontext to EXTENDED i get back different object references. thanks so far.. this was very helpful!!